# How to prevent a CollectionView from rendering until all items in the collection have been added/rendered?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'd like to show a loading message until the collection view and it's subviews have been  completely rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can speicfy an `emptyView` to render when a collection has no items in it. the collection view will handle this automatically. any time it sees the collection drop to zero items, it will render this instead. use that to show your "loading" message.

```
LoadingMessageView = Backbone.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#loading-message-template"
});

ItemView = Backbone.ItemView.extend({
  template: "#normal-item-view"
});

MyCollectionView = Backbone.CollectionView.extend({
  emptyView: LoadingMessageView,
  itemView: ItemView
});
```

Then in your code, you can pass a collection that has not yet been loaded in to the view, show it, and then load it.

```
var col = new MyCollection();
var colView = new MyCollectionView({
  collection: col
});

App.someRegion.show(colView);

col.fetch();
```

This will render and show the collection view, displaying the loading message from the `emptyView` initially. When the collection finishes it's fetch, the "reset" event will trigger and the collection view will re-render with all of the items.

Comment: This is a good solution. However, sometimes there are scenarios where the "Loading" and "Empty" view are diff. For Eg. I have a view showing collection of customers. For a new user this will be empty and i show a "Add Customer" as the first row. Now this is diff from the "Loading" view we are talking about.
What implementation would you suggest in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Can be as simple as this?

```
// code simplified no tested
var MyCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function(){
    $("#loading").show();
    // render stuff
    $("#loading").hide();
  }
});
```

Am I missing something?